# LibGDX gwd not inherit a required module

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, libgdx

I have a error with exporting HTML using GWT.

```
  Errors in 'file:/D:/Dropbox/Programming/Multi-platform/3D%20defence/Dendron3Dv2/core/src/psyrot/td/dendron3d/shop/ShopScreen.java'
     Line 222: No source code is available for type java.sql.ResultSet; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     Line 244: No source code is available for type java.sql.SQLException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

How to add sql or my mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar to inherit in .gwt.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT transpiles your Java code into JavaScript.  The MySQL driver there most likely uses a native interface and therefor can not be transpiled.  If you still want to try, you would have to provide the source files too for the GWT compiler.

Even if you could transform all of this into Javascript, you would most likely don't want your Browser clients to connect directly to your database or have them install MySQL on their local machines in the first place.

In web scenario like this, you are best off using some REST-API (since you are on java already, springboot make this rather easy) and access your data from the browser via this API.  Also see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Networking